# Is there a way to correctly send messages out to all users by unique guids in signalR?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

SignalR has me stumped! I have a list of growing items...that once updated in the database I want to let certain users who "care" about it know.

I don't really care of they are online or not. I just want to trigger a message out to all users who want to know about a change. If they are online, then they see it. If they aren't then it just shows up later in another set of notifications that they see once they log in.

All I have about these users are their unique guids (primary keys in their table) and then information, such as: name and email.

Is there a way to use `Clients.Users(list of users)` in this scenario by alterating information that I already have?

`Clients.All.SendAsync` works perfectly. I just need to really nail down this situation.

I hope that this is clear enough to get me going down the right path!

I am using AspNetCore.

Example information that I have to work with:

```
User1

UserGuid - b7c103d0-78c0-43de-aaa0-1a07cb0c8e46

FirstName - John

LastName - Doe

Email - john.doe@mail.com



User2

UserGuid - cd75274b-19bc-4b8b-8eca-89947959ab03

FirstName - Jane

LastName - Doe

Email - jane.doe@mail.com




User3

UserGuid - df8ede1b-dada-4eec-bc6c-f32b70bd8bd9

FirstName - Bob

LastName - Doe

Email - bob.doe@mail.com
```

What I want to do is send messages to User1 and User3. How do I determine the user information needed for signalR to trigger a message to them only? I don't want to send a message to all

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple questions here that are trickled down based on some other knowledge.

1. Some users care about x, y, or z. - You need to associate your users to what they care about, such as in a database table. How you know that is going to be based on how you create/setup users and how they know about x, y, or z.
2. How to send updates about x, y, or z to just users that care about them. - You can use groups. When a user logs in, get what they care about and add them to that group. When they log out, the get removed from the group. You can send to them using Client.Groups("x").method(message) where "x" is the name of the group. This will send to every member of that group.
3. If they aren't online have it show up later. - This one will require storing your messages and group they should be assigned to in a database. It get's trickier because now you will also have to track if User 1, 2 or 3 has seen a particular message or not. Your going to possibly need to do some additional research on this part. But Google and [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240266/storing-chat-conversations-in-sql-database-using-signalr) have plenty to offer.